# How to handle common data between classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the situation:

I have a bunch of classes that all rely on the same data. So i'm ending up copying all of the required properties across each of my classes and passing it as required.

This means that if there is a new requirement i face the possibility of either having to add a new property to all of the classes that consume the said data or i may have to remove a property from each class in which Ive declared those properties.

I'm developing an asp .net application which has a HTTP handler that parses the query string, get the parameters and then assign them to my base class which can then pass those parameters on to custom control, other classes etc.

Is there a way i can share this data across each class that requires it without including them as properties of each class? What is considered the best practice in this scenario?

**EDIT**

I'm leaning towards the composition solution. I was hoping there might be a better way to share the data without having to add it as a property to each class that requires it. What about creating a class which includes my properties and assigning it to HttpContext.Current.Items object in my HTTP Handler? I could then access the required properties from the HttpContext throughout the application without having to add the property to each class, thoughts? What are the pros and cons of using the HttpContext.Items object?

Answer (score 2):

Favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), give each class that needs the data one property of a common type:

```
public class A
{
    public Record Data { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Record Data { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string FirstName  { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have only one property in each class, instead of duplicating three properties. Also, you will not **have to** create a base class so soon just to share these properties. That is: you now use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: One issue i see with this approach is the multi-dot access - a law of Demeter violation. I would be reaching in to contained classes to get their properties - Class1.Class2.Property.

Comment: @Tester: If it hurts, don't do that :-). Seriously, this is only the first step. The second step would be to identify what you have to do with the values, then put appropriate methods into the new class to do it for you. But that really depends on the details of your software.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution probably is to make a list of the properties which all classes need, and bundle them up into a separate class. Then you can just have one field/property per class which holds an instance of the new class.

Depending on circumstances, you could also create two or three classes, for example if it makes more sense from the domain of the problem, or if some classes only need a subset of the properties.

Comment: This is the solution im leaning towards. I was hoping there might be a better way. What about creating a class which includes my properties and assigning it to HttpContext.Current.Items object in my HTTP Handler? I could then access the required properties from the HttpContext throughout the application without having to add the property to each class, thoughts?

Comment: @Tester Might be a solution. However, this would effectively create a global (session-global, I think) variable, wouldn't it? That *may* be the best solution, but only if almost every class needs it. Otherwise you'll just have to bite the bullet and provide each class with the data it needs.

Comment: If the overhead of passing around all these instances seems onerous, you might want to check out dependency injection, and some of the frameworks (though this is overkill just for this particular problem).

Answer (score 1):

Define configuration class(es) that consolidates the configuration data. Ideally, it would be created (say, with a static factory method) with the data and all its properties would be const/readonly.

The next step is to decide if you'll pass it around at construction time for your classes, have a global registry with this(these) configuration class(es) or other options. I recommend reading Fowler's [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) article for pros and cons of these approaches and how they impact your unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the properties into a base class and have all of your classes inherit from it. Like:

```
public class A
{
     public string Prop1 { get; set; }
     public string Prop2 { get; set; }
     //etc.
}

public class B : A
public class C : A
```

Comment: Ouch. Using inheritance to allow code reuse is problematic. It will tighly couple classes which may have very little in common (apart from needing the same set of values/properties).

Comment: The problem is that the properties are shared among unlike types. It would break the 'is a' relationship.

Comment: @Tester: If the classes are not related have class A as a member inside B and C. It's just composition then.